# Is the free Dirac fermion propagator divergent in 2+1 dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, propagator, regularization

I think it diverges since we have $$g(p)\sim\int dp p^2\frac{1}{p}\sim p^2.$$ So do we need to regularize even a free theory?

Comment: Why are you asking about 2+1 when 3+1 is similar?

Comment: well the system i was working on was 2+1 there is no particular reason.

Comment: OK, I understand.